# Is there a way to reformat a Java String with regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to use a Java regex to change a String to be of a certain format?  For example, I have an input String containing a date & time which can be input with a variety of delimiters, can I use a regex to change it to use a specific delimiter?  If I can, how can I do it?  Currently I'm just checking the input with a regex and then concatenating a new String together with the desired delimiters like so:

```
Pattern dtPatt = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d\\d[/\\-.]\\d\\d[/\\-.]\\d\\d[tT/\\-.]\\d\\d[:.]\\d\\d[:.]\\d\\d");
Matcher m = dtPatt.matcher(dtIn);
if (m.matches()) {
    String dtOut = dtIn.substring(0, 4) + "/" + dtIn.substring(5, 7) + "/" + 
                   dtIn.substring(8, 10) + "-" + dtIn.substring(11, 13) + ":" +
                   dtIn.substring(14, 16) + ":" + dtIn.substring(17, 19);
    // do processing with dtOut
} else {
    System.out.println("Error!  Bad date/time entry.");
}
```

It seems like I should be able to do this with a regex, but a lot of googling, reading, and experimentation has not yielded anything that works.

Comment: As a side note depending on where you put this it could become horribly inefficient because of the compilation of the pattern.

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  Thanks for the thought.  In production I would be processing an unknown - and theoretically unlimited - number of date/time Strings.

Comment: @GreenMatt in that case maybe you should stray away from using the Java Regex and pass it to a separate language such as perl or python.  I may be mistaken, but I believe neither of those languages are compiled and opening a data stream will be less intensive than recompiling the beast every run.

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  Thanks.  I'd prefer to use Python, but can't here ...  :-(

Comment: @GreenMatt perhaps you should show the performance degradation and then your team will be more than happy to go that way :)

Comment: The pattern can just be compiled once and then used repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
    Pattern dtPatt = Pattern.compile( "(\\d\\d\\d\\d)[/\\-.](\\d\\d)[/\\-.](\\d\\d)[tT/\\-.](\\d\\d)[:.](\\d\\d)[:.](\\d\\d)" );
    Matcher m = dtPatt.matcher( str );

    if ( m.matches() )
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        m.appendReplacement( sb, "$1/$2/$3-$4:$5:$6" );

        String result = sb.toString();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println( "Error!  Bad date/time entry." );
    }
```

Two changes

- Change the regex pattern to have groupings, using ()
- Use appendReplacement with a replace pattern where $x uses a specific group matched by the pattern.

Comment: Nice one!  I'm so used to using `appendReplacement()` "correctly" that it took me a few minutes to convince myself this was safe.  The crucial element is that you're using `matches()` instead of `find()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would try

```
DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:dd");

String dtIn2 = String.format("%s/%s/%s-%s:%s:%s", dtIn.split("\\D+"));
DF.parse(dtIn2); // to validate the date produced.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, the whole point of this is to force the date/time String into something a single SimpleDateFormat can handle.

Comment: BTW, I think you mean "ss" (instead of "dd") at the end of your SimpleDateFormat constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Try Matcher's [`appendReplacement()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`appendTail()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) methods. There is a good example in `appendReplacement()`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
Matcher m = p.matcher("one cat two cats in the yard");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "dog");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: OK, but what's the difference to `"one cat two cats in the yard".replace("cat","dog")`? Apart from the fact that your version uses regex and is longer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had already seen this sort of thing, but didn't get it working (nicely) with my set of circumstances.